# xmlns attribute in LINQ to XML query

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I have made the following function in my VB.NET Programm ...

```
Function ReturnTranslation(ByVal CGID As String) As String
        Dim filename2 As String = "D:\\EBSDEMO_4.10.26.1\\CSMapProfiles\\BusinessRules\\ESGOPerson.xml"
        Dim Doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(filename2)

        Dim query2 As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From element In Doc.<BRDatasetNode>.<Translations>.<ESCaptionsDS>.<Captions>
                                                 Where element.Name = "Captions" 'And element.@ID = CGID.ToString
                                                 Select element
        For Each myelement As XElement In query2

            Dim currentElement As XElement = myelement

            Dim MyFirstNode As XElement = currentElement.FirstNode
            Dim MyLastNode As XElement = currentElement.LastNode
            If MyFirstNode.Value = CGID Then

                Return MyLastNode.Value

            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

When The XML below has in element ESCaptionsDS the Namespace attribute  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ESCaptionsDS.xsd"
then the query2 collection inside the function returns --> Enumeration yielded no results !

When i remove this xmlns attrribute everything seems ok!

What can i do ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BRDatasetNode RootNodeType="Entersoft.Framework.Platform.CustomCommands.BRDatasetNode, ESCustomNode" Version="2" CGID="42d7a588-adb7-4bf1-8ed0-fdefe8038267" Dataset="ESGOPerson">
  <system_rules CGID="424034df-a434-4ebf-afe8-b95de8ab380e" />
  <custom_rules CGID="b588a8e2-6ad5-4969-a171-c286da40355d">
  
    <CustomRule CGID="998fd4ed-2ec4-4e33-97cc-354756aa584b">
      <Elems CGID="fbf4c9c6-17e3-4dff-9797-ebdf44fdfe89">
        <BRElemNode CGID="7fcbefe0-4922-4b74-8b77-1355042c2fe1" table="ESGOPerson">
          <conditions CGID="0a5a66dc-e027-4475-a188-21cccf43dd6f" />
          <ValidityConditions CGID="28ed1a57-ae38-4d83-87ea-b26f168a44f0" />
          <ExecuteMessageConditions CGID="07e6f2b5-0649-4517-80ca-65a21df560d6" />
          <OnAboutToSaveTriggerNode CGID="95ecaad6-71f0-4498-af97-f36f66232bf1" />
          <InternalProfileActionNode CGID="d9e41736-c48d-4d0e-b368-54750c175a15">
            <Profile CGID="b5ab3d08-bd96-4c7e-b6d2-6e54703e89f6" UILess="True" Identity="True" Save="False">
              <SourceEntity EntityID="ESGOPerson" />
              <TargetEntity EntityID="ESGOPerson" />
              <SaveExpression CGID="2c139b9a-abad-4b06-a33e-dc2e22d686ab">
                <Supplier>
                  <EnumValue Type="Entersoft.Framework.Platform.Helper.SaveEnum, ESEntity" Value="SAVE_AND_ACTIONS" />
                </Supplier>
              </SaveExpression>
              <RootRule CGID="8a68da7b-04ca-4ed8-b592-8b7835b6b99f" Source="ESGOPerson" Target="ESGOPerson">
                <ExecuteSimpleConditions CGID="dbfabc14-4b02-422e-b0a4-80e87934372d" />
                <Variables CGID="3576cddf-157d-40c6-8cc2-35891551f49c" />
                <Rules CGID="3a9186c2-7d84-4afb-8a36-afe8a6fc00fc" />
                <Conditions CGID="8b0f9519-4ada-4733-bde2-654d492604c4">
                  <Condition CGID="690eae9a-34f0-4217-b842-586d7c8a8baf">
                    <Supplier>
                      <SourceValue>MultilingualName</SourceValue>
                    </Supplier>
                    <FormatParams CGID="3c9f3b4c-7ef2-4014-ac46-105d5ca973d7" />
                  </Condition>
                </Conditions>
                <Assignments CGID="e47ba8c3-acba-44d4-9747-6de3c4ceb30a">
                  <Assign CGID="08568b8b-2281-4ad1-adf0-0525f905d62b" Column="EORINumber">
                    <Supplier>
                      <ConstantValue>From BR !!</ConstantValue>
                    </Supplier>
                    <Conditions CGID="f4ac41a7-4fe6-462c-beaf-543daf8335fd" />
                  </Assign>
                </Assignments>
                <OrderByNodes CGID="e5fbe9a8-00f9-44dd-8e09-aec2a8868438" />
                <GroupByNodes CGID="2ef5fed2-9c6e-426c-bac5-68be34b9abd2">
                  <GroupAtMostEntries CGID="e6717931-55b0-4ff8-8ad9-a4401699b944">
                    <Supplier>
                      <ConstantValue>0</ConstantValue>
                    </Supplier>
                  </GroupAtMostEntries>
                </GroupByNodes>
                <MultiplyByNodes CGID="acd4895a-901d-4efc-952b-714c429b415a" />
                <RowActions CGID="abb2a62c-3ae1-416d-823a-56b98fbc3cab" />
              </RootRule>
              <MapExceptions CGID="7705c048-95bc-45bd-a98b-5036c8a02b9c" />
              <LoginCredentials CGID="6996bb1c-4553-4ff2-bed1-1379e14ee362" />
            </Profile>
          </InternalProfileActionNode>
        </BRElemNode>
        <BRElemNode CGID="d4f8479b-efb4-40ef-aa6f-18f62fe85462" table="ESGOPerson">
          <conditions CGID="02f0260e-a227-48b9-b1ee-5ba35c561002" />
          <ValidityConditions CGID="734ce376-b5b6-4c20-b3ea-432f39b61fc1" />
          <ExecuteMessageConditions CGID="188f609c-3aba-4b7e-8999-208c33063479" />
          <OnAboutToSaveTriggerNode CGID="8ece5eb9-da37-432d-95bf-42a4cf9b2259" />
          <InternalProfileActionNode CGID="153f64c6-145d-43a6-abd3-9142a3debf6f">
            <Profile CGID="9576c174-b5e8-41a7-b0b1-36dd3bd085ba" UILess="True" Identity="True" Save="False">
              <SourceEntity EntityID="ESGOPerson" />
              <TargetEntity EntityID="ESGOPerson" />
              <SaveExpression CGID="25730bbd-219c-41a7-b7cd-91b905527cc9">
                <Supplier>
                  <EnumValue Type="Entersoft.Framework.Platform.Helper.SaveEnum, ESEntity" Value="SAVE_AND_ACTIONS" />
                </Supplier>
              </SaveExpression>
              <RootRule CGID="3c2b9be0-5900-4216-b349-9caaeafe854a" Source="ESGOPerson" Target="ESGOPerson" TargetKey="GID">
                <ExecuteSimpleConditions CGID="bef8d8ed-3c03-46cf-b59b-7579b38819dc" />
                <Variables CGID="1cd5fe30-c781-4428-af38-a3a11e461e33" />
                <Rules CGID="96995077-2740-4164-a4ac-3660eac4e8e3" />
                <Conditions CGID="72c10ea6-cca2-4997-9b14-316a98215a41" />
                <Assignments CGID="e1334ab7-c041-40da-810c-9136c2955732" />
                <OrderByNodes CGID="2ec07a79-0d67-4cf7-b6e0-d049b43a3104" />
                <GroupByNodes CGID="b9e8d2fc-318a-40ff-b6ac-385997197198">
                  <GroupAtMostEntries CGID="d71fe3cd-b2a3-484a-812d-c4e9442ae6ec">
                    <Supplier>
                      <ConstantValue>0</ConstantValue>
                    </Supplier>
                  </GroupAtMostEntries>
                </GroupByNodes>
                <MultiplyByNodes CGID="856b9e25-507f-4427-993f-7a9476bfd028" />
                <RowActions CGID="6afe3d4d-3d68-4825-adce-94985de6f23b">
                  <RowAction CGID="e47f3afd-76eb-4f85-8bb2-5a6ad19c9e8b" ExecLevel="Dataset" trigger="TargetOnPreSave">
                    <Conditions CGID="6fcea0eb-9665-4ed4-9da0-00f5160d8d17" />
                    <CommandRowAction Type="ExternalProfileRowAction">
                      <profile_name CGID="872fe616-5287-472e-ad2c-63f1d2eeefdd">
                        <Supplier>
                          <ConstantValue>CSFormCommands\ESGOPerson\AutomationSetRemarkswithAsk.xml</ConstantValue>
                        </Supplier>
                        <CommandParameters CGID="158de9df-14ca-4c19-899e-a049a7129526" ParamName="RemarksStr">
                          <Supplier>
                            <ConstantValue>χχχχχ</ConstantValue>
                          </Supplier>
                        </CommandParameters>
                      </profile_name>
                    </CommandRowAction>
                  </RowAction>
                </RowActions>
              </RootRule>
              <MapExceptions CGID="ffb15bbe-e6f6-4394-ae3b-58260e36aa39" />
              <LoginCredentials CGID="09c389df-cb46-4a1e-8904-4dce59784300" />
            </Profile>
          </InternalProfileActionNode>
        </BRElemNode>
      </Elems>
      <Conditions CGID="af050b88-7422-4f16-b4cc-cd070debcc2c" />
      <ValidityConditions CGID="d0d56686-3c70-498c-8efd-21d991435e14" />
      <ExecuteMessageConditions CGID="e8f33bdb-bad7-4547-9527-052cec29cd17" />
    </CustomRule>
  </custom_rules>
  <Translations>
    <ESCaptionsDS xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ESCaptionsDS.xsd">
  <Captions>
    <ID>998fd4ed-2ec4-4e33-97cc-354756aa584b</ID>
    <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
    <LangID>el</LangID>
    <Caption>Διακριτικός Τίτλος</Caption>
  </Captions>
  <Captions>
    <ID>7fcbefe0-4922-4b74-8b77-1355042c2fe1</ID>
    <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
    <LangID>el</LangID>
    <Caption>Διακριτικός τίλτλος</Caption>
  </Captions>
  <Captions>
    <ID>b5ab3d08-bd96-4c7e-b6d2-6e54703e89f6</ID>
    <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
    <LangID>el</LangID>
    <Caption>Πρ το Πρ</Caption>
  </Captions>
  <Captions>
    <ID>8a68da7b-04ca-4ed8-b592-8b7835b6b99f</ID>
    <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
    <LangID>el</LangID>
    <Caption>Πρ το Πρ</Caption>
  </Captions>
  <Captions>
    <ID>e6717931-55b0-4ff8-8ad9-a4401699b944</ID>
    <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
    <LangID>el</LangID>
    <Caption>Maximum Entries</Caption>
  </Captions>
  <Captions>
    <ID>d4f8479b-efb4-40ef-aa6f-18f62fe85462</ID>
    <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
    <LangID>el</LangID>
    <Caption>Εκτελεση εκωτ. αυτοματισμού</Caption>
  </Captions>
  <Captions>
    <ID>9576c174-b5e8-41a7-b0b1-36dd3bd085ba</ID>
    <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
    <LangID>el</LangID>
    <Caption>Εκτελεση αυτοματισμού</Caption>
  </Captions>
  <Captions>
    <ID>3c2b9be0-5900-4216-b349-9caaeafe854a</ID>
    <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
    <LangID>el</LangID>
    <Caption>εκτέλεση αυτοματισμού</Caption>
  </Captions>
  <Captions>
    <ID>d71fe3cd-b2a3-484a-812d-c4e9442ae6ec</ID>
    <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
    <LangID>el</LangID>
    <Caption>Maximum Entries</Caption>
  </Captions>
  <Captions>
    <ID>e47f3afd-76eb-4f85-8bb2-5a6ad19c9e8b</ID>
    <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
    <LangID>el</LangID>
    <Caption>Εκτ αυτο</Caption>
  </Captions>
</ESCaptionsDS>
  </Translations>
</BRDatasetNode>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you need to do in the function. Is it based on the matching `<ID>` element value to a function parameter - CGID, return` <Caption>` element value? Please confirm.

Comment: Ted, did you have a chance to try the proposed solution by @miriamka?

Comment: Yes i posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up in the following .
Thank you all !

```
Function ReturnTranslation2(ByVal CGID As String) As String

        Dim ns1 As XNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/ESCaptionsDS.xsd"
        Dim filename2 As String = "D:\\Temp\\File.xml"
        Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(filename2)

        Dim Caption As String = xdoc.Descendants(ns1 + "Captions").Where(Function(x) x.Element(ns1 + "ID").Value.Equals(CGID)).Elements(ns1 + "Caption").FirstOrDefault().Value

        Return Caption

    End Function
```

Comment: It is a copy of the @Miriamka answer. You need to mark her solution as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's *default namespace*. Descendant element without prefix inherit this default namespace implicitly. You can declare a prefix that reference the default namespace and use that prefix starting from `ESCaptionsDS` down to `Captions`, for example:

```
Imports <xmlns:d="http://tempuri.org/ESCaptionsDS.xsd">

...

Dim query2 As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From element In Doc.<BRDatasetNode>.<Translations>.<d:ESCaptionsDS>.<d:Captions>.<d:Caption>
                                         Select element
```

**<kbd>[dotnetfiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GkzKlK)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply , but i still have the same problem when i did the solution you mentioned. I did exactly what you suggested...Stil getting Enumeration yielded no results and when i remove the xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ESCaptionsDS.xsd" from ESCaptionDS element everything works fine ...

Comment: Just want to confirm, did you use the prefix beside adding `Imports`? This part to be precise: `From element In Doc.<BRDatasetNode>.<Translations>.<d:ESCaptionsDS>.<d:Captions>`

Comment: @TedKonstantoudakis Ok, I have to remove the `Where` clause because the intention is redundant with `.<d:Caption>` part and it also wrong because the element is in namespace. I also added a link to demonstrate that the code works

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.
You can use it as a foundation for your function.

It shows the following:

- How to define a default namespace.
- How to use namespaces in LINQ to XML.
- How to query XML in one single statement without any loops.

**VB.NET**

```
Sub Main
    Dim parameter As String = "d4f8479b-efb4-40ef-aa6f-18f62fe85462"
    
    Const FILENAME As String = "e:\Temp\TedKonstantoudakis.xml"
    Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
    
    Dim ns1 As XNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/ESCaptionsDS.xsd"
    Dim Caption As String = xdoc.Descendants(ns1 + "Captions") _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Element(ns1 + "ID").Value.Equals(parameter)) _
        .Elements(ns1 + "Caption").FirstOrDefault()?.Value
    
    Console.WriteLine("Caption='{0}'", Caption)
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
Caption='Εκτελεση εκωτ. αυτοματισμού'
```